# Chromium completely shutting down

Tags: chromium, auto-login

So this may sound a little weird, but my problem is that every time I start Chromium I have to login everywhere again (Facebook, Gmail etc.) no matter when I last logged in the last time.

I turn on my computer and start Chromium (it now asks me to unlock my keyring) and I start Facebook and I'm asked to log in. When closing Chromium now and starting it again I have to login again.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit, on my laptop I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit and the same version of Chromium and there's no problem like that. The main difference I figured is that when shutting down Chromium on my laptop, some chromium-browser processes keep running in the background which don't on my new PC.

Any idea what may be the cause?

Thanks in advance for any help,
Julian

Comment: Since it's been awhile since you posted this—Do you still need help with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe cookies are used for this purpose.

You can check you web cookie settings by clicking the `Wrench` -> `Under the Hood` -> `Content Settings` to see whether cookie setting is allowed.

From there you can click `All Cookies and Site Data` and see whether google cookies are stored.